# TypeError while webscraping using find function in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror, data-mining

I'm trying to scrape a website from timesjob.com but it returns some type of error can you identify the cause? I still can't understand what causes this type of error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
jobs = soup.find_all("li", class_="clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx")
for job in jobs:
    job = job.text
    company_name = (job.find("h3", class_="joblist-comp-name")).text.replace(" ","")
    skills = job.find("span", class_="srp-skills").text.replace(" ","")
    published_date = job.find("span", class_="sim-posted").span.text
    print(job)


print(f"""
Company Name: {company_name}
Required Skills: {skills}
""")

print(" ")
```

This comes to be a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    company_name = (job.find("h3", class_="joblist-comp-name")).text.replace(" ","")
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

what could be the problem with this?

Comment: In the line above, you write `job = job.text`, meaning that `job` is now a string. There is a `str.find()` method, but it doesn't take keyword arguments. I think the `.find()` method you're trying to use is BeautifulSoup's `soup.find()`, in which case just comment out the `job = job.text` line.

Answer (score 0):

The line `job = job.text` is causing issues for the next line, because now `job` is just a string rather than a bs4 tag, so `.find` is [a different function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find) entirely.

Change that line to something like `jobTxt = job.text` (so that you can still use `job`) and then `print(jobTxt)` if that's what you're trying to print at the end of the loop.